# do I need to remove listener for .click / .change / etc?

Tags: javascript, events, listener

When you create event listener .on('click', functionA), it is good to remove the event listener when you don't need it any more with .off('click', functionA);

But does this apply to .click, .change etc as well? do we need to turn these OFF ?

I'm working on a UI that is a single DOM, with hundreds of JS pages, so I wonder if these click events are out there being unnecessary listeners and affecting performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.on('click', functionA) is the same as .click() as .on('change', functionA) is the same as onchange() so I would think so.